# Describing polka dot and background color

Tags: word-choice

When you say **yellow polka dot bikini**, does it mean a bikini with yellow dots or a yellow bikini with dots in another color?

How do you properly describe the color of the polka dot pattern?
If the **dots are black** and the **background is yellow**, is it enough to just say "**black-yellow polka dot dress**"? or do I have to say "**yellow dress with black polka dots**"?

Comment: A yellow bikini with black polka dots.

Comment: Even as a child I was never sure whether the bikini was yellow with polka dots of some other colour or some other colour with yellow polka dots; but I did know that she was afraid to come out of the water.

Comment: I'm upvoting the question because I find it intriguing. However, I'd like the post to show what research you've done.

Comment: Should we not assume the bikini is basically yellow, and has a polka dot pattern on top of that base colour? Isn't this really the same as a contraction of "a red dress with (white) trim"? Ie, could "a polka dot bikini with yellow" mean anything like as much as "a yellow bikini with polka dots"?